# A tool as part of a dialog box

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, python-addin, wxpython

I have a button created using Python Add-Ins which pops up a dialog box which is built using wxpython. I am wondering if I can place a tool (Select Layer by Location) within that dialog box to get location coordinates of layer (basically select that layer). Once a layer is selected, it will fire back some values to the already open dialog box. Any word of advice on whether it is possible and how to create a class for tool would be very helpful here.

Comment: Not so much the 'select by location' tool that's already on the ArcMap toobar.. the relationship goes one way: custom buttons on ArcMap, not ArcMap buttons on custom form. You can make your own 'custom select by location' though... is that what you want to do?

Comment: I want a tool within a custom dialog box which gives same functionality as 'Select by Location' tool -- A custom 'select by location' is what I am looking for as long as I get layer location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot. A GP Tool dialog is not an embeddable wx control.

Comment: Can I embed a tool within custom dialog then to get XY location by either using Python Add-Ins or wx?

Comment: The best you can do is add an add-in tool to a toolbar that pops up your custom dialog in the `onMouseDownMap` event. Then your user would select a point and then fill out your form.

Answer (score 0):

I think the key here is the *custom dialog box*, if you're writing your own you could put all kinds of stuff on it. I've not done any python addins but have done a great many in C# that do all sorts of useful things.

The python form is a wxDialog http://www.wxpython.org/ which looks to operate in a similar manner to QT for QGIS.